# Strongly typed-views and shared views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using the default MVC project which Visual Studio sets up, I have a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file which sets up a shared 'master' view.

I'm currently working off the assertion that; wherever possible you should use a strongly-typed view, just because this feels cleaner. (Please correct me on this point if it's wrong)

I'm thinking of having my shared 'master' view accept a `PageModel`, which could contain things like `PageTitle`, `User`, `Locality` etc.

Should all of my data models then inherit from `PageModel` so that the 'master' view and the different page views can handle models of different types? I'm just trying to get a feel for MVC best practice.

**Models**

```
public class PageModel {
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class DataModel : PageModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@model Namespace.Models.PageModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@Model.Title - Website Name</title>
        <!-- etc etc -->
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Namespace.Models.DataModel
```

---

**Edit**

Assuming the above approach is sound, how would you handle views which should accept a list of items when the 'master' view is still expecting a single model?

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@model Namespace.Models.PageModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@Model.Title - Website Name</title>
        <!-- etc etc -->
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.DataModel>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Are your models coming from a database?

Comment: I read something about wrapping database models rather than using them directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So really the wrapping of your models is creating a view model, the view model normally contains your model and any other view data you might need. Creating a view model base class is a great way to go to ensure consistency in your view models.

You can then use your view model base exactly as you have described (i.e. setting the @model in your _Layout class).

So in summary - your method is totally fine, just maybe the terminology is slightly different.

EDIT: 19/12/2013 0 RE: List based views

The simplest way to handle this is that you expose the list of items as a property of your view model - i.e. don't use @model IEnumerable instead create a view model that exposes IEnumerable, for example:

If you had a model of type Book:

```
public class Book { ... }
```

And a view model (or PageModel as you call it) base

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase { 
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

You would have a view model like this:

```
public class BooksViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.DataModel> Books { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is sort of a related follow-up, how should you handle list views with this approach? (See question edit)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this done a variety of different ways, it really depends on the project.

One method is to set the `<pages pageBaseType="CustomWebViewPage">` in the view configuration to a class that inherits `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` and extend the custom class with a `User` model or other domain specific global properties.

I prefer to have the page title overridable from the `ViewBag` since it provides greater flexibility on simple pages.

Comment: I've found myself sympathising with those who discourage the use of `ViewBag` mainly because there's no control over what can be placed in there

Answer (score 0):

Just don't type your `View` and the `Model` property will be there as an `object`. You can do a safe cast and use it, on layout, for sample:

```
@{

  PageModel pageModel = this.Model as PageModel;

  if (pageModel != null)
  {
     <div>obj.Title</div>
  }  

}
```

It is valid for Partial Views too.

Now, if you are sure that every action of all controllers that can return a `View` that is using the `Layout` page, just cast and use Model.

[Look this article.](http://philjthorne.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/strongly-typing-aspnet-mvc-masterlayout.html)

Comment: That article suggests he is advocating the approach I outlined? "As long as you follow basic inheritance rules strongly typing the model on the master/layout page is perfectly safe"